# Error en consola programa Java "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, java-8

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]ya busqué y traté varias soluciones sin embargo ninguna parece funcionar.
Tengo un programa con 5 clases, estan todas en el mismo paquete.
Al ejecutar la clase "Serie" me tira errores de que no reconoce las variables y clases de la q está heredada.
Dejo solo una pequeña parte de lo que me tira por consola para resumir, porque siempre es el mismo error pero repetido en distintas variables y clases, desde el IDE el programa anda bien, solo que por consola me tira ciertos errores pero son como si no encontrara aquellas clases que usa.
Calculo que es porque no encuentra esas clases, pero no le encuentro sentido.

PD: Tampoco me reconoce el uso de "super".

```
ERROR
public class Serie extends GeneroCinematografico {
                           ^
  symbol: class GeneroCinematografico
Serie.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
                ", titulo='" + titulo +
                               ^
```

EDIT: Estoy ejecutando con

> javac Serie.java

Al proyecto ya le hice clean, rebuild, intenté poner classpath pero por alguna razon siempre me tira error de que no reconoce el comando (tal vez lo estoy poniendo mal). Las clases estan bien importadas, el error no sale desde el IDE. Es decir, al ejecutar el programa desde el IDE todo sale correcto. Mi problema es desde la terminal.

Espero puedan ayudarme! Saludos

Falta agregar (no me deja aca en Stack), el error del import, pero es igual que todos los demas

```html
➜  Coursera2 javac src/com/company/Serie.java
src/com/company/Serie.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
public class Serie extends GeneroCinematografico {
                           ^
  symbol: class GeneroCinematografico
src/com/company/Serie.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
                ", titulo='" + titulo +
                               ^
  symbol:   variable titulo
  location: class Serie
src/com/company/Serie.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
                ", genero='" + genero +
                               ^
  symbol:   variable genero
  location: class Serie
src/com/company/Serie.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
                ", creador='" + creador +
                                ^
  symbol:   variable creador
  location: class Serie
src/com/company/Serie.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
                ", duracion=" + duracion +
                                ^
  symbol:   variable duracion
  location: class Serie
src/com/company/Serie.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
                ", visto=" + visto;
                             ^
  symbol:   variable visto
  location: class Serie
6 errors
```

Comment: Hola, si no agregas el código es muy dificil ayudarte con tu problema. Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código pertinente por favor

Comment: que editor usas? que versión java y de jdk?

Comment: Pon la sentencia con que estas ejecutando por consola. Por lo que mencionas es muy posible que sea el classpath.

Comment: @AlvaroC. ahí edite, estoy ejecutando con "javac Serie.java"

Comment: @RuslanLópez Hola, Intellij idea, java 1.8.0_241

Comment: De acuerdo. Creo que ya se que pasa, en seguida respondo.

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que tienes el paquete:  **mi.paquete**
Y dentro de ese paquete tienes las siguientes clases:

GeneroCinematografico, Serie, Disco

Donde la clase Serie usa a las clases Disco y GeneroCinematografico de una menara como la siguiente:

```
package mi.paquete;

public class Serie extends GeneroCinematografico{

    private Disco disco;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Ejecutando");
    }
}
```

Es decir tienes una estructura de paquetes y clases como sigue:

[image: estructura de archivos]

Dado este entorno para compilar por linea de comandos debes colocarte en el directorio padre del paquete. Como en mi ejemplo las clases están en el paquete **mi.paquete**  debo lanzar la compilación en el directorio **compilacion** hacia la clase o clases que deseo compilar.

[image: lanzando compilación]

Y para ejecutar usarías algo como:

[image: ejecutando]

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta Alvaro, pero no me funcionó lamentablemente. No entiendo que es lo que está pasando. Decidí crear un proyecto nuevo, copiando las clases y me sigue sin reconocer las clases que se heredan. Incluso me desconoce el "import" mientras que desde el IDE funciona correctamente. Será algo del classpath? No sé configurarlo bien

Comment: A ver, edita tu pregunta, ponle imágenes de tus directorios y de como estas ejecutando el javac. ¿que sistema operativo usas?

Comment: macos, ya subo todo

Comment: ya edité. Espero que puedas ayudarme! Muchas gracias

Comment: prueba a lanzar el javac desde dentro del directorio src es decir: javac com/company/Serie.java

Comment: FUNCIONÓ!!!! MIL GRACIAS!!! @Alvaro C

Comment: te hago otra consulta, hace un ratito funcionaba bien y ahora me dice ➜  src javac com/company/GeneroCinematografico.java
➜  src Java com.company.GeneroCinematografico
Error: no se ha encontrado el método principal en la clase com.company.GeneroCinematografico, defina el método principal del siguiente modo:\n   public static void main(String[] args)\nde lo contrario, se deberá ampliar una clase de aplicación JavaFX javafx.application.Application. Cuando "GeneroCinematografico" no es la clase MAIN. no entiendo porqué me pide que herede la clase de Application

Comment: @programmergi para otra consulta haz otra pregunta

Comment: Si te ha servido, favor de marcar la respuesta como correcta. Si has hecho otra pregunta favor de avisar cuál y si no te han ayudado con gusto te apoyo.